I don't understand this function notation
I do not understand what it means for there to be something other than a simple variable like "$x$" or "$y$" etc. inside the "input bracket" for a function ( $f(x)$, $f(y)$, etc.). For example, I do not understand what the notation in the second line of the image means:

Translation to English: "Going back to our topic, Taylor, a disciple of Newton, was, among other things, interested in the problem of writing out functions using other functions that were simpler. At that time, it was already known that the polynomial function $f(x)$ of degree $n$ (...) could be written as (...)."
Can someone please explain to me what is means in general to have something other than just one letter in the "input bracket" and in particular what it means in this example and why? Is it just a matter of notation?

A common way of thinking of a function is that it takes an input, does something to it, and produces an output.  With that model in mind, the object in the parentheses after the name of the function is the input of that function.
For example, if a function $g$ is defined by the formula $g(x) = \sin(x)$, then
$$g(y) = \sin(y), \qquad
g() = \sin(), \qquad
g(a+b) = \sin(a+b), \qquad\text{etc.}
$$
Or a more complicated looking example: if $h$ is defined by the formula $h(x) = \sin(x)\mathrm{e}^x + x^2 + x$, then
$$h(y) = \sin(y)\mathrm{e}^y + y^2 + y \\
h() = \sin()\mathrm{e}^{} + ^2 + , \\
h(a+b) = \sin(a+b)\mathrm{e}^{a+b} + (a+b)^2 + (a+b),
$$
and so on.
This is basically just a find-and-replace:  look at whatever is in parentheses on the left, then take all of the $x$s on the right and replace them with whatever was in parentheses.
In the example given in the question,
$$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dotsb + a_n x^n $$
where, presumably, the $a_j$ are constants.  Then
$$ f(a+h) = a_0 + a_1(a+h) + \dotsb + a_n (a+h)^n. $$
In the provided text, this has been simplified by grouping like terms renaming the coefficients of the resulting terms.  For example, if $n=3$,
\begin{align}
f(a+h)
&= a_0 + a_1(a+h) + a_2(a+h)^2 + a_3(a+h)^3 \\
&= a_0 + a_1 a + a_1 h + a_2 a^2 + a_2 ah + a_2 h^2 + a_3 a^3 + 3a_3 a^2h + 3a_3ah^2 + a_3 h^3 \\
&= (a_1 + a_1a + a_2a^2 + a_3a^3) + (a_1 + a_2a + a_3a^2)h + (a_2 + a_3a)h^2 + a_3 h^3 \\
&= c_0 + c_1 h + c_2 h^2 + c_3 h^3.
\end{align}
Note that the only change in the last line is the coefficients have been renamed.  For example $c_2$ is "just" the coefficient of $h^2$, i.e. $c_2 = a_2 + a_3a$.

It's perhaps worth mentioning one more example: If $$f(x) = x^2 + x, $$ and you're asked to figure out what $f(x+1)$ is, then $$f(\leftrightsquigarrow) = (\leftrightsquigarrow)^2 + \leftrightsquigarrow, $$ and therefore $$ f(x+1) = (x+1)^2 + (x+1) = x^2 + 3x + 2. $$
